# Clob & JSON parsing vs dedicated table for the nodes in JSON

Tags: python, json, django, oracle

We are currently evaluating various data layer designs for a project.

We have `JSON` data (not more than `few megs` & less than `500` nodes all inclusive) coming in from various sources. We have finalized on 2 approaches. Also we expect not more than `500` concurrent requests.

1. Store the `JSON` as `CLOB` in DB, and `python json` module to parse and extract required `fields` used by the web application.
2. Design table for the `JSON nodes` and store it in a dedicated `oracle table` and retrieve for use with the `web application`

Need any 3rd degree view/suggestions, before our POC and performance testing.

Thanks for your help. I know the question has broader scope but I think it is specific enough to be considered here.

*UPDATE:*

1. We use Oracle 11g
2. Requirement is not for reporting but for displaying content on the Web app
3. The web app is expected to be have `10k-30k requests /day`, and we would be parsing JSON for every request. So that's `10k-30k` times/day.

   4. This is just one part of the bigger web app.

What we are trying to establish is, `is it worth having 500 odd columns (many tables)` **vs** JSON parsing which can be handled with Python dicts which are faster anyway.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  If you're using 12.1, Oracle provides native support for JSON http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246 which may be a third option.  Beyond that, it's going to depend on how often you'd need to parse the JSON, what sort of reporting you need to do, what your bottlenecks will be, etc.  Other than prototyping each approach and measuring what works best for your application and your environment, it's hard to guess.

Comment: How many times is a particular JSON string going to be parsed?  If half the strings are never parsed, most of the rest are read and parsed once, and only a handful are read many times, it makes far less sense to parse them on input.  If each JSON string is being read a thousand times, it probably makes more sense to parse it up front.  How often do new elements get added that you want to display?  I'm not sure what you're saying when you say that Python is "faster anyway"-- faster than what?

Comment: Not all JSON fields will be parsed at the same time, but definitely each may hit a few thousand parses/day. Since we have 500 odd fields (which could be min 5 tables), we are thinking if handling as JSON would be better than joining/fetching data from 5 tables at a time. By faster anyway, I meant in python JSON is parsed to dicts which use hash tables so must be faster.

Comment: So you're saying that each row is going to be read (and potentially parsed) thousands of times a day?  If you're only expecting a few 10's of thousands of reads per day, that implies that you only have a few 10's of JSON strings.  Can that really be right?  That's certainly possible but it's pretty unusual.

Comment: Yupp, the unusuality is taking us for a task here. The app depends on fields based on various business rules, so at any given point not more than 50 fields will be used. If all was used we would certainly be banking on table & DB server, but since it is mere 10% (which agains varies on business case) that will be used per request, we are stuck. Now we are planning to evaluate NoSQL document stores.

Comment: @TheStart I have had this scenario quite a few times, but every time we went with leveraging relational capabilities DB. Never did a comprehensive analysis, do let us know the results of your analysis & conclusi